# I cannot run mediaelement.js properly

Tags: jquery, html, mediaelement.js

I spent almost 2 hours and still can not make it work, i put a test file here (using mediaelement.js' video to avoid conflict with codec). you can see it here:

[ikperawang.com/test.html](http://ikperawang.com/test.html)

As you see i already set it as html5, the path is correct, but still mediaelement.js cannot play the video

Can anyone test and let me know what did i miss ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell MediaElementJS to render your video explicitely via javascript.

```
<body>
<video src="images/videos/echo-hereweare.mp4" width="320" height="240"></video>
<script>
    $('video').mediaelementplayer();
</script>
</body>
```